# Can I detect the moment of a value is just assigned to a table in Lua?

Tags: lua, variable-assignment, watch

I made an interactive command shell which is operating by Lua interpreter. User input some command, shell calls something like `lua_dostring` to execute it. I want to allow users to define their own functions in arbitrary table, and save it to separated storage (like a file) automatically. According to the manual, I can get exact source code input by user with `lua_Debug`.

It looks possible to save the functions sources to some files after all execution done. But I want to save automatically when it's just added/remove.

Can I detect the moment of some value is just added to a table?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If you have a table `tbl`, every time this happens:

```
tbl[key] = value
```

The metamethod `__newindex` on `tbl`s metatable is called. So what you need to do is give `tbl` a metatable and set it's `__newindex` metamethod to catch the input. Something like this:

```
local captureMeta = {}
function captureMeta.__newindex(table, key, value)
    rawset(table, key, value)
    --do what you need to with "value"
end

setmetatable(tbl, captureMeta);
```

You will have to find a way to set the metatable on the tables of interest, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do this with metatables:

```
t={}
t_save={}
function table_newinsert(table, key, value)
   io.write("Setting ", key, " = ", value, "\n")
   t_save[key]=value
end
setmetatable(t, {__newindex=table_newinsert, __index=t_save})
```

Here's the result:

```
> t[1]="hello world"
Setting 1 = hello world
> print(t[1])
hello world
```

Note that I'm using a second table as the index to hold the values, instead of `rawset`, since `__newindex` only works on new inserts.  The `__index` allows you to get these values back out from the `t_save` table.